# How to update git submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-merge

I have just done a `git merge <merging_branch_name>` in the app and resolved many conflicts.

But when I do `git status`, I can see list of submodules with (new commits) in the message.
It looks like the submodule (branch/tag) versions have not been updated.

For example:

```
modified:   plugins/myplugin.git (new commits)
```

How do I update the submodules with the versions (with the `<merging_branch_name>`)

I get like this in git bash

```
my_app (current_branch  |MERGING),
```

so when I do `git status`, I get list of submodules as below

```
 modified:   plugins/plugin1.git (new commits)
 modified:   plugins/plugin2.git (new commits)
 modified:   plugins/plugin3.git (new commits)
 modified:   plugins/plugin4.git (new commits)
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: `git add <submodule_path>`, just as if it was a file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To update a submodule content to the new SHA1, this should be enough:

```
# the submodule content needs to be updated
git submodule update --init

# the parent repo needs to record the new submodule SHA1
git add plugins/myplugin
```

Comment: I get like this in git bash  my_app (current_branch  |MERGING), so when i do git status, i get list of submodules as below

 modified:   plugins/plugin1.git (new commits)
 modified:   plugins/plugin2.git (new commits)
 modified:   plugins/plugin3.git (new commits)
 modified:   plugins/plugin4.git (new commits)

Comment: So, is it by running 1) git add plugins/myplugin  then 2)git submodule update --init will resolve this ?

Comment: (assuming the submodules SHA1 are the correct one, which they should be after a merge). If not see xxMUROxx's answer.

Comment: "git add" did not get the plugins updated to the latest versions

Comment: @Vinay add alone isn't enough. `git submodule update` is needed. And it will update only to the SHA1 recorded by the parent (`git ls-tree HEAD | grep 'plugin1.git'`).

Comment: I did git submodule update and then git add <plugin_path>, it seems the versions have been update,  (submodule update then add  solves the issue)

Comment: @Vinay Ok, I have reverse the order in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Let us say you have two branches `master` and `hotifx`. In `master` the head of the submodule is at `123456` in `hotfix` at `abcdef`. (let us say that `abcdef` is newer than `123456`). If you have checked out `master` and merge `hotfix` the submodule head will move to `abcdef` but the code in the submodule is not checked out to this new head. If you enter now `git diff` you will see that the submodule points to `123456` but this is not correct, since you want to point to `abcdef`.
If you would now enter

```
git add pathToSubmodule
```

the old `123456` is added to the index. This is the wrong commit. What you have to to is to move the head to the correct commit and this is done by simple calling

```
git submodule update
```

Comment: I suggested not to `add` otherwise you will have in `master` the submodule commit `123456` and not the newer `abcdef` which comes from mergin `hotfix`.

Comment: yes, i did run git add which made me to retain in the same branch

Comment: i did not get the plugins updated to the latest versions

Answer (score 1):

Submodules basically point to a specific commit in the submodule that was used when making a commit in the parent git repository. It seems that after your merging, the submodules are *ahead* of what is expected after the merge. You have two choices:

- go back to the commit where the submodule currently points to
- update your parent repository to use the new submodule states

The first option was pointed out by the others as

```
git submodule update
```

The second option, and I think this is what you are asking for, is done with

```
git add plugins/plugin?.git
git commit -m 'update submodules'
```

which will update your HEAD state to store the current submodule references.

---

You can check what is going on by looking at

```
git ls-tree HEAD | grep 'plugin1.git'
```

before and after updating the submodule. Compare this reference to the current commit in this plugin:

```
cd plugins/plugin1.git
git rev-parse HEAD
```